# Unable to load ssh2.so extension

Tags: php, openssl, xampp, lamp, ssh2-sftp

Im getting an error loading ssh2 extension in lampp. 
This is the error that I receive when I use this command
 `/opt/lampp/bin/php -r "print_r(stream_get_wrappers());"` 
`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ssh2.so' - /usr/local/lib/libssh2.so.1: symbol EVP_aes_256_cbc, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
Array
(
    [0] => https
    [1] => ftps
    [2] => compress.zlib
    [3] => compress.bzip2
    [4] => php
    [5] => file
    [6] => glob
    [7] => data
    [8] => http
    [9] => ftp
    [10] => phar
    [11] => zip
)`

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: what so funny there ?